# BCP changing header column order

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-server-2012, export-to-csv, bcp

I am trying to run the below query:

```
BCP "select * from myTable " queryout C:\Temp\myTable.csv -t, -c -T -S
```

Table:

```
Process  Verb   Match
P1       V1     FALSE
P2       V2     TRUE
```

CSV:

```
Match    Process    Verb
P1       V1         FALSE
P2       V2         TRUE
```

For some reason, BCP is sorting the header row alphabetically.

The above command used to work absolutely fine in SQL Server 2008 R2, but for some reason it's messing up in SQL Server 2012... How can I fix this?

Comment: Weird behavior! What if you try: `bcp "select Process, Verb, Match from myTable " queryout C:\Temp\myTable.csv -t, -c -T -S`? Or  `bcp myTable in "C:\Temp\myTable.csv" -c -T -S`

Comment: @gofr1  :
There are a few problems with this approcah: 1- I am creating this on the fly with dynamic number of columns, 2 - Number is columns can be upto 150-200, 3 - It used to work in sql 2008 R2

Comment: Did you install the latest service pack for SS2012? Second: if you script the table (from SSMS, right click table and script CREATE), is the order of columns as you would expect?

Comment: Are you sure your query and BCP connect to the same db? Same server? What if you dump the column order through BCP and check if it is still what you expect? I dump data through BCP in SQL 2012 all the time and never had this issue to be honest.

Comment: @TT. - Yes, If I right click and select the columns from SSMS, they come in correct order.

Comment: Suppose you do the following: (1) you script the table, change its name (add an `_`) and run the create statement. (2) copy the original table to the new table (`insert into table_ select * from table`). (3) drop the original table. (4) change the new table name to the old name. Then do your export again... what does that give?

Comment: @ajeh - I tried bcp "select Process from myTable" queryout C:\Temp\mytable.csv -t, -c -T -S but still it printed Match as the column header in the csv with [Process] column's data.

Comment: @TT - I tried this approach too (although I was reluctant to try it in the first place itself) but didn't help.

Comment: You are using a trusted conection with a server name? What if you try `select @@servername as srv, db_name() as db`? Would that output the server and DB names that you expect to be connected to?

Comment: yes, it does that. Are you using any configuration for bcp ? Is there a version involved?

Comment: @ajeh - I just ran this command -  EXEC master..Xp_cmdshell 'bcp -v', the version that I have is 12.0.5000.0 , which version do you use?

Comment: You're running the BCP command through `xp_cmdshell`? If so I could cook up a script that makes a query that has all column names sorted by ordinal position from `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: yes, I am using xp_cmdshell to run BCP and I have already tried specifying the column names in the correct order

Comment: @Ishan Was my answer of any value to you?

Comment: @TT: There is something wrong with the bcp I am using, the query didn't work. To improvise I even filtered out the column names which are taking up the first few places but BCP simply ignored it. BCP is just taking the column in my table and sorting out the headers by itself, even if I select only one column which is the last column by the ordinal position.

Comment: @Ishan That's real weird. I tested the script before posting on a test database I have... worked like a charm. Can you verify that the generated BCP statement is 8000 or less characters? Other than that, I'm out of ideas. Other than reinstall, test on other databases, other versions of SQL Server and try see what's different.

Comment: Yes, I printed the BCP statement before executing the command and it was definitely less than 8000 characters. Seems like BCP is following some weird configuration setting to sort out the header row which I am unable to find at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128392/discussion-between-ishan-and-tt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It wasn't BCP, it was Syscolumns table in SQl which was causing this.

I was reading the column headers from sys.syscolumns. While in Sql 2008 R2, id field in sys.syscolumns is unique for each column of table, it gives the same values in Sql 2014.

So, when I run below query in Sql 2008 & 2014 separately

```
SELECT distinct name,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber FROM    sys.syscolumns 
   WHERE   id = OBJECT_ID('MyDB.dbo.MyTbl')
```

In Sql 2008, it gives the data ordered by id which is unique for each column. However in Sql 2014, since id is same for all the columns, it sorts the results alphabetically.

Now, I changed my query to

```
SELECT distinct name,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY colid) AS RowNumber FROM sys.syscolumns
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('MyDB.dbo.MyTbl')
```

Comment: This is why it's so important you include a [MCVE] so that people can reproduce your problem. Your question does not contain the least bit about `sys.syscolumns`. If you had, people could have helped you sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try create a query that selects the columns in the order as found in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION`, like in the script below:

```
DECLARE @target_table SYSNAME='myTable';
DECLARE @target_file VARCHAR(1024)='C:\Temp\'+@target_table+'.txt';

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(8000)=STUFF((
    SELECT 
        ','+QUOTENAME(column_name)
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE 
        TABLE_NAME=@target_table
    ORDER BY    
        ORDINAL_POSITION
    FOR XML
        PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    1,1,''
);

DECLARE @bcp_cmd VARCHAR(8000)=
    'BCP ' + 
        '"SELECT '+@cols+' FROM '+QUOTENAME(@target_table)+'" '+
        'QUERYOUT "'+@target_file+'" '+
        '-t, -c -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME();

--SELECT @bcp_cmd;

EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcp_cmd;
```